I am not able to upload MEDIA Files in Django Vercel server
I get this error:
ClientError at /dashboard/add-profile-details
An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://www.karlowebsytz.com/dashboard/add-profile-details
Django Version: 5.0.6
Exception Type: ClientError
Exception Value:    
An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
Exception Location: /var/task/botocore/client.py, line 1021, in _make_api_call
Raised during:  dashboard.views.create_profile
Python Executable:  /var/lang/bin/python3.12
Python Version: 3.12.3
Python Path:    
['/var/task',
 '/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
 '/opt/python',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
 '/var/runtime',
 '/var/lang/lib/python312.zip',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.12',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
 '/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
 '/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages',
 '/opt/python']
Server time:    Thu, 11 Jul 2024 12:24:06 +0000

This is my settings.py configuration
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'myid'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'mykey' #(I have the actual values in my project)

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'karlowebsytz'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

This is my Vercel.json file
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "karlowebsytzweb/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "karlowebsytzweb/wsgi.py"
    }
  ]
}


My s3 policy and cors are below
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1720667374556",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1720667373352",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::karlowebsytz",
                "arn:aws:s3:::karlowebsytz/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

and cors
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]


I was trying to upload files in my website forms but when I submit I get 404 and sometimes 400 error code but my website works fine when I am submitting forms on my local server.
